# API calls to Apps in AKS intermittently returning 503 Errors

Tags: azure-aks, istio

We have a solution with multiple applications hosted in the AKS cluster. The UI and other third party application make calls to the API in the AKS cluster. Some of the applications within the AKS also make API calls to the other end points within the AKS cluster. In front of the AKS, we have the Azure APIM and istio for routing traffic and load balancing.

Now, we're seeing some requests to some of the API endpoints are getting 503 responses to the caller. Sometimes, an API call to an endpoint within one Applications was still responding successfully, then a few seconds later, an API call to a different endpoint within the same Application is returning 503. We have increased the minimum/maximum replicas for the scaling out within the AKS cluster. But that did not resolve the issue. And this issue is happening to multiple applications, even though some endpoints more likely having this issue than others.

From one of the API caller, occasionally we'll see the following message in Response-Body captured in AppInsights:
*upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED*
However, we could not figure out where this is being generated.

Obviously the applications are not in "unavailable" or "not ready" state. Also, the problem could be happening around midnight when the system is not busy. Where could this 503 code be generated? And why?

Any helps and pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: 503 Service Unavailable errors are generally thrown by proxies, load balancers, or other network components when they cannot connect to the target service, either because the service is down or because there's some transient network issue. Given that you have both Istio in your architecture
Check the Istio proxy logs. For the services/pods that have been affected by 503, get the logs of the Istio sidecar containers (istio-proxy).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've checked the istio logs and no indication of any errors during the problem timeframe. On the Azure APIM portal, we can only show the failed request without any details. Same is with the Azure AppInsight log analysis. 
I've updated the post to include some error message that we've seen.